# Crear VBA UDF con IF, AND, OR, THEN, ELSE statements

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi, powerquery

Necesito crear una serie de reglas sobre un listado de productos para asignarles una nueva descripcion.

No lo puedo hacer con una formula normal porque excel tiene un limite de caracteres a la hora de escribir formulas, y el listado de productos es largo.

Pongo un ejemplo armado en PowerQuery de lo que necesito.

```
each if [Familia] <> "ESPUMOSO" and [Marca] = "TRIVENTO RESERVE" and [Cepa] = "MALBEC" and [Formato] = "B0750" and not Text.Contains( [txtProducto], "ORGANIC" ) then "Trivento Reserve Malbec"
else if [Familia] <> "ESPUMOSO" and [Marca] = "TRIVENTO RESERVE" and [Cepa] = "MALBEC" and [Formato] = "B0750" and Text.Contains( [txtProducto], "ORGANIC" ) then "Trivento Reserve Malbec Organico"
else if [Marca] = "GENERAL" or [Marca] = "GENERICO" or [Marca] = "SEG SEL VINO VESTIDO" then "Saldos de Exportacion"
else "No aplica"
```

Necesito aplicar estas mismas reglas en una UDF, donde Familia, Marca, Cepa, Formato y Descripcion(original) sean las variables de la formula, y las reglas sean las mismas que el codigo de arriba. Para el resto de los productos puedo copiar el codigo y modificarlo.

Gracias!!

Comment: Esto no tiene sentido. Crea la/s tablas necesarias para que tengas la relación Marca/Cepa/Fprmato con Exportación y lo tienes solucionado.

Comment: No hay necesidad que hagas un comentario en una pregunta que no quieras contestas. Ya probe lo que de forma condescendiente me sugeriste, pero la cantidad de caracteres que excel permite a la hora de escribir una formula es de 8.192. Al armar una formula con todas las reglas para asignarle una descripcion a los productos, excede esa cantidad.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código VBA que tienes desarrollado y dónde estás atascado?